# Sending time data type from Android to mySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I was trying to send two types of data, Time and Int. The time will be coming from a time picker and the int from a spinner. The problem is whenever I try to send the data to the database by pressing a button, the application will crash (Unfortunately, AppName has stopped working). What I tried to do was send the value from the time picker to a TextView. The string on the TextView will then be sent to the request queue, *addURL* and data shall be processed by the php script *addFeedSched.php*

The android app was developed on android studio. The localhosting was done through WAMP server. Handling the data was processed by php scripts. The method used on android was volley

Below are the contents of the java file of the activity and the php scripts that were used as well. Comments were added so to minimize confusion.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FeedingSched extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Parameters for Time Picker
    Button button_picktime;
    TextView show_time;
    static final int DIALOG_ID=0;
    int hour_x, minute_x;
    //--

    // Parameters for Feed Amount Spinner
    Spinner spinner;
    // Array Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    //--

    // Parameters for Adding Schedule
    Button button_addsched;
    //--

    // Request Queue Variable
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    // Accessing localhost server through php script's directory (note that was just edited here)
    String addURL = "http://myIPv4:8080/feedingsched/addFeedSched.php";

    // --

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feeding_sched);

        // -- Initialize Spinner Object
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.feedamt_spinner);
        //Initialize Array Adapter Object
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.feed_amt,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // --
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // -- Provides a method that invokes a toast when an item is selected
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        // Declaring variables from components (buttons, textview, etc)
        button_picktime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picktime_bttn);
        show_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeset_txt);

        button_addsched = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addsched_bttn);
        showTimePickerDialog();

        // -- Request a queue for the updateURL php
        button_addsched.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, addURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("sched_time",show_time.getText().toString());

                        return parameters;
                    }


                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }

    // Time Picker Initializer
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_ID) {
            return new TimePickerDialog(FeedingSched.this, kTimePickerListener, hour_x, minute_x, false);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Time Picker Listener
    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    hour_x = hourOfDay;
                    minute_x = minute;
                    show_time.setText(hour_x + ":" + minute_x + ":00");
                }
            };


    // Showing Time Picker Dialog
    public void showTimePickerDialog() {
        button_picktime.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


}
```

**PHP Scripts that were used**

**addFeedSched.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connection.php';
    inputInterval();
}

function inputInterval(){
    global $connect;

    $sched_time = $_POST["sched_time"];
    $feed_amt = $_POST["feedamt"];

    $query = " Insert into feedingsched(time, feedamt) values('".$sched_time."','".$feed_amt."');";

    mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('hostname','localhost');
define('user','root');
define('password','axlrosel123');
define('databaseName','aps');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);

if($connect)
{
    echo "Good";
}
else{
    echo "Bad";
}

?>
```

**EDIT** Here is the logcat message, but it seems to be providing unnecessary details while I was testing the app. The app was also tested on my phone and through connecting it and the local server with the same network.

```
04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20917: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20919: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20923: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    04-17 13:18:30.940 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 518: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    04-17 13:18:30.990 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.933MB for 2362992-byte allocation
    04-17 13:18:31.010 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    04-17 13:18:31.010 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 459: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    04-17 13:18:31.010 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    04-17 13:18:31.010 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 461: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    04-17 13:18:31.020 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    04-17 13:18:31.020 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 308: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    04-17 13:18:31.030 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    04-17 13:18:31.030 23265-23265/com.example.axlroseljaro.automatedpoultrysystem W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 153 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
```

Comment: consider post your logcat error

Comment: Done, the logcat message was added. Though, I cant find the right info for my case

Comment: Doesn't  `requestQueue.add(request);` needs to be initialized first. I know you created it. But you haven't initialized it

Comment: How do I initialize it? I thought I already did. @MDMalik

Answer (score 0):

This is how you initialize it

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
// Instantiate the cache

Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.

Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
```

For reference, please refer [Setting Up a RequestQueue](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#network)